# Why does my C++ implementation of pnpoly always return true?

Tags: c++

I am a beginning C++ programmer and have been learning how to code as part of work I am doing to help prepare analyses for a specific instrument for a set of nuclear chemistry/physics experiments. This particular script was written to run in the ROOT (http://root.cern.ch) analysis package, which uses C++ as its scripting language, which is why it does not have a main() function and does not define a namespace. It could be altered a little bit to compile as a standalone executable, but I haven't bothered as the purpose of this script is to test parsing of data files (which is working correctly) and then check if a user-provided x,y coordinate is inside the polygon. The polygon x,y coordinates are generated by a different ROOT script I wrote which saves a text file containing the vertices as the user proceeds through 2D representations of data and marks the area of interest.

My problem lies in the implmentation of the pnpoly algorithm. Because the part of the script that knows which datafile to grab is known to work, I temporarily disabled all of the code that asks questions in order to narrow down which file to pull from and put in static values. As the script is right now, it only asks the user for the x, y coordinate to test.

The code parses the datafile, counts how many vertices there are, and builds two float arrays, one of which contains all of the X coordinates and the other which contains the Y coordinates; this is how I understood pnpoly to work. Because ROOT does not let you make functions within its scripts, I modified the pnpoly code slightly and passed in my vertex count and arrays directly, along with an unnecessary (the final code won't include it) boolean variable.

My problem is that with any point I have tested so far, the pnpoly function is returning 1/true. I have tested, for example, the point 7000,1000 which lies far outside the area of interest. My understanding of C++ is not yet advanced enough to understand how the vector algorithm works, although I do understand its logic of even/odd boundary crossing counts to determine whether the point is inside or outside the polygon.

Why does the pnpoly part of the code not seem to properly detect where the user-defined x,y coordinates are?

The pnpoly part of the script:

```
bool inPoly;
int i, j, c = 0;
for (i = 0, j = vertices-1; i < vertices; j = i++) {
  if (((PointsY[i] > InputY) != (PointsY[j] > InputY)) && (InputX < (PointsX[j]-PointsX[i]) * (InputY-PointsY[i]) / (PointsY[j]-PointsY[i]) + PointsX[i]))
c = !c;
  if (c = 1) {bool inPoly = true;} else {bool inPoly = false;}
}
if (inPoly) {
  cout << "Test point " << InputX << "," << InputY << " is inside the peak." << endl;
} else {
  cout << "Uh oh. The test point " << InputX << "," << InputY << " is not inside the peak." << endl;
}
```

And here are the sample data points for this test which are stored in the arrays:

```
Line 0: X: -1000.63 Y:  6754.28
Line 1: X:  4639.49 Y:  2639.52
Line 2: X:   5718.2 Y:  3107.11
Line 3: X:  6365.43 Y:  3890.31
Line 4: X:  6149.68 Y:     4580
Line 5: X:  5019.61 Y:  4205.93
Line 6: X:  4218.28 Y:  3527.93
Line 7: X: -1000.63 Y:  6754.28
```

The editor on this site doesn't seem to like my code, so the full script (not just the pnpoly part) can be seen at http://pastebin.com/Nk6srJfp.

Comment: You redeclare inPoly when you assign to it, hiding the original declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you have an assignment in an if statement:

```
if (c = 1) {bool inPoly = true;} else {bool inPoly = false;}
```

Maybe you meant this?

```
if (c == 1) { inPoly = true;} else { inPoly = false;}
```

EDIT: Took François Moisan's comment also.

Comment: Such a simple goof! Thank you. It works now! It's been great fun to start learning C++ and this site has been a great help. Hopefully in time I can help others. Accepted this after making both changes and testing the script. Now for the fun part: integrating this with the rest of the software for this project.